# Select a value from a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn, so please forgive me for what should be an obvious answer:

Trying to compare the password on the db to an "old password" field, but it wasnt comparing as true, so when I print the password I get from the db I get:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [password] => 7ed5a78c36a55c07c26469345a00609b ) )
```

instead of only the value for the password, which would be what I'd like to compare with the user input for the old password.

I have it like this:

```
function edit_member($user_info, $old_pass)
{
    $id_user = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
    $user_pass = $this->db->query("SELECT password FROM membros WHERE id_user='" . $id_user . "'")->result();
if (md5($old_pass) == $user_pass) {
        $this->db->where('id_user', $id_user);
        $this->db->update('membros', $user_info);
        redirect('/cpanel');
    } else {
        //redirect('/edit_account/edit');
        print_r("A password não coincide");
        echo anchor('/cpanel', 'Voltar');
```

Comment: your stored password seems to be encrypted with md5, so it will never match with your provided password. You need to encrypt provided password as well with md5 and then match this string with string of database password.

Comment: try md5($old_pass) == $user_pass[0]->password

Comment: @ Gokul Shinde

But that's why I do "md5($old_pass) == $user_pass"

$old_pass is the input from the user, where $user_pass is what I retrieve from the db - shouldnt this encrypt the value the user inputs and then compare it to the encrypted value from the db?

Comment: @Yair.R
Thanks! that's it!

Cheers,
Baya

Comment: Cheers! :) By the way, I recommend you to learn about better hash passwords since md5 is not secured. Use BCrypt - password_hash(), password_verify()

Comment: Will take a look at that, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your are using CodeIgniter for your application. The CodeIgniter model returns the value or results in object or array format. So to simplify your code you can update your code with following code.

```
function edit_member($user_info, $old_pass)
{
    $id_user = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
        $user_pass = $this->db->query("SELECT password FROM membros WHERE id_user='" . $id_user . "'")->row();
      if(isset($user_pass->password) && md5($old_pass) == $user_pass->password){
              $this->db->where('id_user', $id_user);
              $this->db->update('membros', $user_info);
              redirect('/cpanel');
        }else {
             //redirect('/edit_account/edit');
               print_r("A password não coincide");
               echo anchor('/cpanel', 'Voltar');
       }
}
```